# node https.get how to validate 401

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I need to validate the 401 which is an authorization error, but need to display an alert, this is my code but I don't know how to send this to the front.

```
}).on('end', () => {
                    console.log('response.statusCode ', response.statusCode );
                    if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
                        console.log('error section');
                        error = new Error('Request Failed.' + `Status Code: ${response.statusCode}`)
                        console.log('error->', error);
                        res.send(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log('success section');
                        res.send(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understand your question...

```
if( response.statusCode === '401' ){
// alert
console.log('validation errors')

// get validation errors

res.status(401).send(yourValidationErrorsFound);
}
```